# I have a Problem with a border from a button tag

Tags: html, css, button, border, fieldset

I made an button with this code:

I already added some CSS code:

```css
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3f9a39;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
fieldset{
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" id="submit" value="Submit">Ihre Nachricht absenden</button>
</fieldset>
```

At the moment it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSxKG.png

You can see that I have a border but how can I remove the border ?

I already tried it with:

```
    border: none;
    outline: none;
```

Sincerely yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `fieldset` not with the button. Try this

```
fieldset {
   border: none; // or use border:0;
}
```

**Live DEMO**

```css
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3f9a39;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
fieldset{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" id="submit" value="Submit">Ihre Nachricht absenden</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you accept it as answer so that the issue will be marked as resolved. Thank you.

Comment: sure - sorry I'm new here so didn't know every functions from stack overflow.